# why I get a `expected ';' before 'RegistrationHandler'` in my c++ code

Tags: c++

why I get a `expected ';' before 'RegistrationHandler'` in my code, cant find the error?

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // this is where the server is started etc
    Application app(argc, argv);

    // localization support
    QTranslator translator;
    QString locale_string = QLocale().name();
    QString filename = QString( "MyApp_%1" ).arg( locale_string );
    if (translator.load(filename, "app/native/qm")) {
        app.installTranslator( &translator );
    }

    new MyApp(&app);

    const QString uuid(QLatin1String("abc"));
    RegistrationHandler *registrationHandler = new RegistrationHandler(uuid, &app);

    return Application::exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-indented your code, it was hard to read.

Please show how the declaration of `RegistrationHandler` works, there's no `#include`s shown in this code and clearly it's not declared in the included code, either.

Comment: I dont understand, when I remove the line with the RegistrationHandler  everyting is okay

Comment: this was the error: i did not import the header :( but why my eclipse did not give me this hint. thank you

Comment: That error is a common compiler message from VisualStudio meaning "unknown symbol".  For whatever reason, the compiler is unable to be more helpful.  So just learn this lesson well, and you'll know where to look first next time. :)

Comment: @Mordachai, you are wrong. C2061 is issued after C2065. 2065 says the identifier is undeclared. It is just how error list is sorted.